# Waves and osciilation

Tags: homework-and-exercises, waves, acoustics

When intensity  of sound increases increases to 10 times level of sound increases by 10 decibel why and how the sound intensity is related to sound level

Comment: Easily found at a variety of websites.  Wikipedia, hyperphysics, etc. Do a search.

Answer (score 1):

Decibels are defined as:
$$
L_P = 10\log_{10}\left(\frac{P}{P_0}\right)
$$
This is not unique to sound, any quantity with units of power can be represented using decibels. Decibels are a ratio between two powers, on a logarithmic scale. With regard to sound pressure, sound pressure $\rho_s \propto P^{1/2} $ so:
$$
L_\rho = 10 \log_{10}\left(\frac{\rho^2}{\rho_0^2}\right)=20\log_{10}\left(\frac{\rho}{\rho_0}\right)
$$
The value is decibels in usually given is in reference to the standard sound $\approx 20~\text{mPa},$ which is roughly the quietest sound that can be heard by the human ear. The choice of reference is arbitrary as you can define decibels with reference to any sound pressure.